# Android - Adapters in fragments issue

Tags: java, android, fragment, adapter

I am fairly new to android development and when I try to work with adapters in fragments I get an error, I tried to write this line under the `onCreateView`

```
valueAdapterEn = new ValueAdapterEn(English_list, this);
```

this error is in this section `(English_list, this)`

**ValueAdapterEn**

```
public class ValueAdapterEn extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private ArrayList<String> English_List;
private ArrayList<String> Filterd_EngList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ValueFilter valueFilter;

public ValueAdapterEn(ArrayList<String> English_List, Context context){
    this.English_List = English_List;
    this.Filterd_EngList = English_List;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    getFilter();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return null;
 }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
Error:(84, 30) error: constructor ValueAdapterEn in class ValueAdapterEn cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: ArrayList<String>,TwoFragment
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

**the problem may be with 'this'**

Comment: Have you created **ValueAdapterEn**?

Comment: @AparajitaSinha yes of course I have

Comment: Please share your LogCat Message Error

Comment: Post the constructor of `ValueAdapterEn` please

Comment: the parameters may not be matching with the constructor

Comment: What does the adapter extend?

Comment: I added the LogCat, please take time to review it

Comment: Your adapter is expecting no args when called. Remove them and your code should work

Comment: First of all, it's not going to with [this] instead of [getActivity()]. If this does not help, please provide some code like class declaration and constructors at least. I believe you need to implement required constructor.

Comment: I added the constructor

Comment: That is not the constructor, that is the class definition. I strongly suggest to do as @Soham said and try some java tutorials first

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson Can you post your full class `ValueAdapterEn` .Your question is totally too-broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your **ValueAdapterEn** Constructor  is not taking the Context:

You have to instantiate your context like below ;

```
  public class ValueAdapterEn extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
  private Context context;
     public ValueAdapterEn(ArrayList<String> English_List, Context context){
             this.context = context ;
   }
   ......

  }
```

Comment: I added the constructor

Comment: in this part "this.context = context" I have the cannot resolve symbol error

Comment: Can you Please provide the whole LogCat Error

Answer (score 2):

You have create this `ValueAdapterEn` class with no arguments in the `constuctor` as the log message shows there I guess.How can you pass arguments in the `class`.Please also post your relevant code for more help and also learn `core-java` first before deep digging into some `android` code.You can lean about `constructor` from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Comment: This. I'm just wondering how he's not getting an error in IDE editor

Comment: I added the constructor

Answer (score 0):

instead of `this` you have to pass `context` Or `getActivity()`

Comment: I added the LogCat, please take time to review it, and I tried getActivity() but it didn't work

Comment: i think you don't declare a constructor with those params

Comment: Please don't post guesses as answers.

Comment: I added the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment yet, but I guess the adapter there requires a context, which you're trying to pass in the second argument. A fragment is not a valid context. Use `getActivity()` instead of `this`.

Comment: I added the LogCat, please take time to review it, and I tried getActivity() but it didn't work

Comment: I looked at it. Looks like your instantiation has too many or too few arguments. Can I see you constructor?

Comment: Please don't post guesses as answers.

Comment: as I said I am not familiar with such words, excuse my ignorance but what is exactly a constructor ??

Comment: @IulianPopescu I'm trying to help them and I can't comment.

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson the beginning of the class. The part that says Public class ValueAdapterEn extends ......

Comment: You don't help if you post random thoughts (excepting the fact that the same answer was already posted). To give a proper answer wait until you can be sure that what you say will fix the problem

Comment: I added the constructor

Comment: @IulianPopescu The same answer was posted literally as mine was going through. Call it a race condition. As to whether or not I'm helping, I'm sure that's OP's call.

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson That's the class definition. Inside it, you will find Public ValueAdapteEn( and then a bunch of stuff. Can you post that?